# How make spacemacs with clojure layer to complete function in dependency automatic

Tags: emacs, clojure, autocomplete, spacemacs

As titile, my use spacemacs and add `clojure` layer.
And I add a dependency in `project.clj`, but it cannot complete the function  automatic.

Here is some of my configuration:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
 (auto-completion :variables
                  auto-completion-enable-help-tooltip t
                  auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t
                  auto-completion-enable-sort-by-usage t)
 better-defaults
 emacs-lisp
 (git :variables
      git-magit-status-fullscreen t
      git-enable-github-support t
      git-gutter-use-fringe t)
 github
 markdown
 org
 syntax-checking
 version-control
 clojure
 )
```

When I import a dependency, I do not know which function it offers, so I want to emacs help me to complete automatic, or is there someway else to achieve my goals.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `require` a dependency give it a name like this:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [com.ok.my-library :as library])
  ... )
```

then in your code when you type

```
library/
```

spacemacs/emacs will create the drop down of names offered by that namespace. adding the `:as name-here` is generally a help to others exploring your code later as well.

If your emacs is not populating that list that would be a problem independent of this one (both need solving).

Comment: Yes, I do the exactly you write, and there is no drop down of names offered, so I am not sure what is the problem. I think add `auto-completion` and `clojure` layer should be worked.

Comment: Thank you for help me. I realized that I need to add require buy the command of `cljr-add-require-to-ns` instead of type myself, and it works that drop down menu appear.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some important points to realize here for someone who is rather new to this. I'll try to point them out.
Everything here applies to a mostly unconfigured Spacemacs with clojure and auto-complete layers active.

Keep in mind:

1. the REPL is not actually the command line interface, but the background process running that you can interact with (for example via the command line interface) - that process has some relevant internal state (current namespace, required symbols and namespaces, loaded/evaluated code)
2. the more interesting interaction with the REPL often is not via the command line, but in the Editing Window (meaning Emacs Window) itself

You do that by using the Cider evaluation commands, to be found via keys `<leader>-m-e` in Spacemacs. What I say primarily applies to that style of interaction.

3. interaction between Cider REPL and Autocomplete has in some ways more to do with evaluation/ns-`load`ing than with ns-require

Now for the question:

- when you `cider-jack-in` into a fresh REPL, ns-declarations in no Editing Window or Buffer are evaluated - you are in `user`-ns
- the **autocomplete-layer** in the context of Cider seems to complete only, but also all, things that are declared (with that particular `:as`) in some ns-declaration that has at some time been *evaluated*, or more probably, `loaded` (not required)
- when you `cider-eval-sexp-at-point` (for example) in a Window, the namespace-declaration in the buffer is evaluated, which typically triggers some requires (not the entire buffer is evaluated though)

You might run into problems because there are some weird ways in which `ns`-requires are evaluated, which seem to be connected to whether a required `ns` is open in some Buffer in your Emacs. I am not sure this is the correct explanation, but it seems to me that

- if you have `ns`-1 open in some buffer, evaluating `ns`-2 that
  `:refer`s your `ns`-1, only the referred ns-form is evaluated, not the
  buffer
- if you don't have the `:refer`ed ns open, the ns and all forms in its
  file are loaded

So sometimes it becomes necessary to "manually" evaluate all forms you reference in some `ns`, so that requires can be resolved. You might do this with `cider-evaluate-buffer` or load the ns some other way.